# Passing an argument to a view from panel display in Drupal

Tags: drupal, view, panels

Currently I've got a content type in Drupal that is a list of fields that must be filled out. To then sort that content and display it, I have a View created that imports all the fields from that content type and filters by published and node type.

This view has a URL and an argument set up that filters those results based on one of the content fields, not taxonomy. For example, I am declaring whether these records are 'current' or 'past' and the argument is set, now, so that if a user types URL/current or URL/past they will see the view display the respective content, be it past or current.

My objective here is to create a panel that will display this view in one pane and on the left hand pane, have a navigation list with links to URL/past URL/current etc. which will link to the same panel page only with an argument. This argument can then be passed down to the view, changing it respectively.

Is this possible- if so, how? I have worked on this issue for several days and the resources I come across are all several years old and non-helpful. Thank you.

Comment: In short, I want a nav list on the left, to drive a pane on the right by telling it what view (and with what arguments) to display within the pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel page should be receiving virtual path elements, like my_page/%/% and the panes should be sending %1 or %2 to their views correspondingly. The panel panes view displays can be created in views and then inserted through panel interface. The arguments can be configured in view panel pane display config.

OR, you can simply create a view that receives and argument, and do a *views_embed_view()* in the panel pane set to PHP filter - then you can simply pass *arg(1)* and *arg(2)* as a variable.